# SignalR vs NuGet on VS2013

Tags: signalr, nuget

I create a web application project on VS2013, using the default MVC template, nothing more (.net 4.5.1, MVC5). Now I'm simply trying to run this on the PM Console:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
```

I am, however, met with this error:

```
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Input string was not in a correct format.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], FormatException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

While searching through, i found that indeed there are problems with nuget + signalr, but no solution is working for me. What have i tried:

- Installing specific versions of Microsof.Owin and Microsof.Owin.Security (tried with 3.0 and 2.0)
- Cleaning all solution packages and restoring

What i haven tried is to run the regsvr32 command, for i dont have admin privileges.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: The `Input string was not in a correct format.` message can be a result of  a Resharper bug. If you have Resharper I would try disabling it to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: That fixed it. Care to make it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

The `Input string was not in a correct format.` message can be a result of a Resharper bug. If you have Resharper I would try disabling it to see if that fixes the problem.